Briggs engine will only run on choke; cannot remove jet
I have a Toro snowblower with a Briggs "0841 32 0120 E8" engine (084132?) that will only run (well) on full choke (though it will run poorly on half or no choke). I have pulled the carburetor off, and while everything looked pretty clean, I cannot get the jet out of the tube. There's a threaded... something (don't know what to call it)... in the tube, which comes out fine, and then the jet starts threading out and binds up.
There seems to be good fuel flow into the bowl, so that jet is my primary suspect. Is there a trick to getting it out or otherwise cleaning it, or should I just replace the whole carburetor, which seems to be available for $17 locally?

My opinion? Just change the carb and be done with it. If you can get it for $17, that'd be well worth it and avoid all the headache. JMHO, though.
